# ndk The filename or extension is too long

Tags: c, android-ndk

I am trying to build a shared object for Android using ndk-build command, the source compiles fine but then I get this error:

```
make (e=206): The filename or extension is too long.
```

If any body can tell me what causes this problem and how to fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the command line.

Comment: What do you do that causes this error? Which file name is it complaining about?

Comment: the build process took about 15 mins for compilation giving Like ("Compilethumb : ModlueName <= "sourcefile.c") for every source file then this (SharedLibrary  : libngspice.so) and then it just started to build the compiled files this was the error in the end ([all the objectfiles .o] -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -l
c -lm -o D:/MyFiles/Android/Datte//obj/local/armeabi/libngspice.so, ...) failed.

make (e=206): The filename or extension is too long.
make: *** [D:/MyFiles/Android/Datte//obj/local/armeabi/libngspice.so] Error 206)

Comment: I started a new build process now and dumping it into a txt file, I will post a link to pastebin with its contents when it is finished

Comment: Here is the [command line output](http://pastebin.com/rUdsKSfx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You hit the [Windows command length limit](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473). You should use some static libraries as a workaround. Typically, people compile branches of their source tree with separate Android.mk files that end with `include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)`, and then list these as `$(LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES)` in the "main" **jni/Android.mk** that ends with `include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)`. Your `ndk-build` will load this "main" makefile, so it should *include* (explicitly or using some nesting approach) all the static library makefiles.

But this is only a convenience. You can achieve the same result if you use single **jni/Android.mk** file as you have now.

You may also find it easier to list the static libraries as `$(LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES)` - this way you guarantee that the order of listing these libraries will not cause linking problems.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but I have like 1450+ c source files scattered in multiple folders and sub folders as you can see from the command line output, and I think it would take a considerable amount of time to split up my andorid.mk file to multiple make files and combine them, that would be my last resort of course, but is there a way to compile that Android.mk file without the command line (I am running windows 7), I mean another application that is not bound to the Windows command length limit (8191 characters) you mentioned above, I used eclipse builder but it gave the same error.

Comment: Would it be easier to use ubuntu rather windows 7 to build?

Comment: As I explained, you can keep everything in a single Android.mk file, and the split may be done by simply adding some "separators" in a semi-automatd manner. I could help you with that if you put your Android.mk in pastebin or similar.

Comment: That would be appreciated, here is the [Android.mk](http://pastie.org/8413914) file, Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, you put me on the right track to solving this, I tried your code as is and it gave some undefined reference issues, because some of the static libraries has dependencies in other libraries, it's my job now to fix these issues.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to resolve the dependencies. Try http://pastie.org/8415024 with LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES instead.

Answer (score 5):

You can add this to Application.mk
APP_SHORT_COMMANDs :=true

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe as a workaround, you can try to subst the directory "D:\MyFiles\Android\Datte\obj\local\armeabi\objs\ngspice\spicelib" for a drive letter, using:

```
subst X: "D:\MyFiles\Android\Datte\obj\local\armeabi\objs\ngspice\spicelib"
```

This could save some space and generate a smaller command line. However, it might not solve your problem, depending on the Windows command length limit, as Alex Cohn answered. Besides, you'll have to change your makefile and change, for example,

```
D:/MyFiles/Android/Datte//obj/local/armeabi/objs/ngspice/spicelib\parser\inp2y.o
```

for

```
X:\parser\inp2y.o
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't think it will work, as this [Windows command length limit](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473) Alex Cohn refrenced says I only have 8191 characters limit to commands, and I have 1450+ source files which means I can't get it going by reducing the path length, file names alone would exceed that limit.

Comment: Would it be easier to use ubuntu rather windows 7 to build?